# Using HTML form to pass values of check boxes in Servlets using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, html, servlets

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloServlets/Hello?Maths=on
```

Servlet Name = "Hello Servlets"
Servlet class = "Hello"

It works just fine with above passed URL String. However trying to pass the values from HTML form,

The URL string formed is

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloServlets/checkbox?Maths=on
```

and then of course I get resource not found.

Follows the HTML form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Please add your Details</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <form action = "Hello" method = "Get" target = "_blank">
 <input type = "checkbox"  name = "Maths"/>Maths
 </br>
<input type = "checkbox"  name = "Physics"/>Physics
</br>
</br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Select Subject"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Invalid break tag

```
</br><!-- not this -->
<br/><!-- try this -->
```

***Grouping checkbox***

Data is send in `name=value` pair.

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Maths" name="Subject"/>Maths
<input type="checkbox" value="Physics" name="Subject"/>Physics
```

In the servlet use:

```
String[] Subjects = request.getParameterValues("Subject");
```

Comment: @Arvnd: That may or may not work, but that's not what I want to do. I am after the issue and not making it work.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm , It seems to work here as suggested on website, so it should be working  anyway

Comment: @Simran, can you try to get rid of those extra spaces in the tags?, I mean this `type = "checkbox"` likewise others as well.

Comment: Those spaces never actually existed in my original code. Formatted it nicely anyway but no help

Comment: @Simran, kindly replace the break tag

Comment: and that worked :D How ? Could you please throw some light how come this innocent looking break tag was the culprit here?

Comment: Yeah, `</br>` wasn't here valid a self-closing tag and the browsers don't complain for this. Self-closing tag have forward slash to right side of the tag name like `<br/>, <hr/>`, etc.